# ReactJS ExpressJS - Ajax Form

Tags: ajax, node.js, email, express, reactjs

Due to my starting level with `React` and `Node`/`Express` and, above all, time restriction, I'm developing a `single page application` without `database`, so I have only `static` pages.

I've configured `react-router` to have clear url, using the `hash` (`http://localhost:8080/#/contacts`) i avoid also server calls:

```
let history = createHistory({
  queryKey: false
});
```

I've got the necessity to send `mail` from my `form`. To do this I've found [nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) and I need to invoke it from an `ajax` call.
Just to do some pratique with React i've configured my ajax call in my `componentDidMount` function:

```
openForm() {
    $('#contacts-form').on('submit', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/mail',
            type: 'post',
            data: { msg: $('#data').val() },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('err form');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.openForm();
}
```

Now, after I've installed `body-parser` and set my `form's action` to "`/mail`", in my `server.js` I've configured my `.post` route

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/mail', function(req, res){
    res.send('ajax call recived');
});
```

So now once I try to submit my form, my ajax call fails, in the console, I get this error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/mail 404 (Not Found)
err form
```

It's the first time I'm working with these tools, where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like your post can't find the route your specified. Could you maybe post a bit more info about the call beign made? 

`Console > Network > <Your post call>`

(need to have network tab open before submitting)

Comment: Damn, shame on me. It works, I've forgot to relaunch the server...!!

Comment: That explains the 404

Comment: Exactly, thank you anyway!